# Laravel multi image upload

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to save multiple images but I get the error show in the image at the bottom of the post.

I have tried doing a request of the name, but I get another error, I have a one to many relationship between property and images, I am trying to save many images of a property.

If I am receiving the image, if I make a dd before the creation I receive the image.

store method

```
public function store(Request $request)

{
  /*--from this session you start to save the properties with all their attributes  --*/
  
    $properti = new Propertie;

    $detail = new Detail;

    $detail->antiquity = $request->antiquity;
    $detail->furnished = $request->furnished;
    $detail->floor = $request->floor;

    $detail->save();

    $properti->details_id = $detail->id;

    $properti->name = $request->name;
    $properti->price = $request->price;
    $properti->description = $request->description;


    $properti->departaments_id = $request->departaments;
    $properti->municipalities_id = $request->municipalities;

    $properti->property_type_id = $request->type_property;
    $properti->offer_type_id = $request->type;


    $properti->details_id = $detail->id;

    $properti->lat = $request->lat;
    $properti->lng = $request->lng;
    $properti->address = $request->address;


    if (isset($request->property_id)) {
        $property_type = $request->property_id;
    } else {
        $property_type = null;
    }
    
    

    $properti->save();
    
    $image->name = $request->name;
   
        
        foreach($request->file('images') as $image ){ 
            $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move('image',$name);
        }
    
    
    $properti->images()->create(['name' => $name ]);



    $piso_id = $properti->id;
    $space = new Space;

    $space->property_id = $piso_id;
    $space->bedrooms = $request->bedrooms;
    $space->bathrooms = $request->bathrooms;
    $space->parking = $request->parking;
    $space->area = $request->area;


    $space->save();

    $properti->spaces_id = $space->id;


    foreach ($request->input('characteristic') as $characteristic) {

        $charc = new Characteristic;

        $charc->property_id = $piso_id;
        $charc->characteristic = $characteristic;
        $charc->save();
    }


  

    Session::flash('message', 'Se ha registrado su propiedad De forma exitosa');

    return redirect()->action('PropertyController@index',compact('name'));
    // return view('properties.index',compact('properties'));
}
```

File input

```
<div class="custom-file">
                    <input required type="file" class="form-control" name="images" placeholder="Imagenes" multiple>
                </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this error happens only if there are no images attached. You should attach the image while looping over the request data:

```
foreach ($request->file('images') as $image) { 
    $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image->move('image', $name);
    // v- TO HERE -v
    $properti->images()->create(['name' => $name ]);
}

// MOVE THIS: $properti->images()->create(['name' => $name ]);
```

Comment: I do it like this but the image and the id do not save me

Answer (score 0):

as i see, you are calling a variable $name defined inside a foreach loop which mean it's not defined outside the loop, and that's what the error said.

Comment: PHP doesn't have loop scope; variables defined inside of loops persist until the end of the function scope. [See fiddle here](https://implode.io/CmHG0C)